# Android. KeyFactory RSA implementation not found

Tags: android

I have a class that extends Application. In onCreate() method I start some thread, that calls:

```
KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
```

Normally it works perfectly, but from time to time (very rare) I get such exception:

```
W/System.err(24537): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyFactory RSA implementation not found
W/System.err(24537):    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
W/System.err(24537):    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
W/System.err(24537):    at java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyFactory.java:81)
```

It looks like a race... I think the security system is not initialized at moment my thread is calling for "RSA".

Is this a known issue? Can anyone provide me with some hints?

I get this issue on 4.0.3 device (don't know about other versions).

**More details:**

I've tried such code:

```
Provider providers[] = Security.getProviders();

try {
    k1 = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e1 = e;
}

try {
    k2 = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e2 = e;
}

try {
    k3 = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e3 = e;
}

if(k1 == null || k2 == null || k3 == null) {
    if(e1 != null)
        e1.printStackTrace();

    if(e2 != null)
        e2.printStackTrace();

    if(e3 != null)
        e3.printStackTrace();
}

for(Provider provider : providers) {
    System.out.println(provider.getName());
}
```

And this is what I get from time to time:

```
k1 is null
k2 is <key>
k3 is null


e1.printStackTrace();

    04-20 22:09:33.322: W/System.err(17249): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyFactory RSA implementation not found
    04-20 22:09:33.322: W/System.err(17249):    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
    04-20 22:09:33.322: W/System.err(17249):    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
    04-20 22:09:33.322: W/System.err(17249):    at java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyFactory.java:81)
    ...

e2 
    null

e3.printStackTrace();
    04-20 22:10:08.512: W/System.err(17249): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyFactory RSA implementation not found
    04-20 22:10:08.532: W/System.err(17249):    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
    04-20 22:10:08.532: W/System.err(17249):    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
    04-20 22:10:08.542: W/System.err(17249):    at java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyFactory.java:81)
    ...


providers

    AndroidOpenSSL
    DRLCertFactory
    BC
    Crypto
    HarmonyJSSE
    MyProvider
```

While most of the time I get all k1, k2, k3 initialized...

It sounds like getInstance("RSA", "BC") is a solution (althought I don't understand why), but the problem is that BouncyCastle can be missed on some Android devices (as far as I know), so I should NOT specify "BC" in this call... So again, I have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

What device is this? It's not a race, the Harmony provider simply doesn't have an RSA implementation. The BouncyCastle provider does though, so it should be able to get it from there. Try specifying the provider name explicitly:

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
```

Comment: Interesting, did not think that RSA can be missed on some devices... BTW, I get this error on same device (asus eee pad, 4.0.3) from time to time, so in my case the RSA provider is always here.

Comment: Even if the support RSA for signing/verifying, not all providers providers support RSA key generation and/or export/import. Android has at least three JCE providers, of those BouncyCastle has the most algorithms/mechanisms. If you don't specify the provider explicitly,  `getInstance()` should get the implementation from the one that supports it (usually BC). If it only works sometimes, it might be a bug indeed.

Comment: I dumped providers and their properties, the only one who supports RSA is "BC version 1.46"... Curious, when/how security providers loaded? Is there any way to wait until all providers are loaded and ready to be used?

Comment: I'll have to check for details, but provides should be initialized by the system when it boots, there is generally no need to wait. You might look at logcat to see if there are any system errors or warinngs.

Comment: We were having this issue on Moto devices. Adding "BC" worked